# How to debug where a 404 error is being called from

Tags: css, less

I have a setup in which all of my less files are compiled to a single css file, which is included in the head of my page, yet somehow, the less files are still being called somewhere, and since they are gitignored, when I deploy I am getting a bunch of 404 errors. It doesn't actually affect the page (since I'm just using the CSS file), but I want to prevent the errors. See the attached screenshots.

Anyone know how these files are being requested or where I might look / how I might debug it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Migrated from the comments, where OP indicated this was the answer:</sub>

> courses.css includes its [sourcemap](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors) (see the very end of the file) referencing all those less files (so it seems Chrome tries to request them when you have its Developer tools open). You need to disable the sourcemap generation for your production builds.
>
> – [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) – [Jan 22 '15 at 0:54](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079180/how-to-debug-where-a-404-error-is-being-called-from#comment44537939_28079300)

Answer (score 0):

One of your CSS files contains an `@import "somefile.less"` that didn't get preprocessed?

Comment: I checked - couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: The file responsible for creating the 404 requests is courses.css - when I remove it they go away, but inside courses there are absolutely no import statements. And nothing referencing any .less files